# Javascript RegExp to check if any other character in string

Tags: javascript, regex

only following characters are allowed in the string

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ( ) -

I want to check if string contains any other characters

Comment: So you want to check for anything that _is not_ a comma or a digit? So... `/[^\d,]/g`?

Comment: so use not with the allowable characters

Comment: `/[^\d\(\)]/g` [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/r1a2hm/2) I suggest trying out sites like these

Comment: How to use not with allowable characters?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you what you need, but it will also detect spaces:

```
/[^\d()-]/g
```

Example:

```
var foo = 'hello1234567890()-world';

// Will match 'hello' and 'world'
var bar = foo.match(/[^\d()-]/g);

if(bar) {
   // Invalid input
} else {
   // Is valid
}
```